# Solving $\sqrt{25 - 10x + x^2} = x-5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, quadratics, radicals

I need help solving this math question.

$$\sqrt{25-10x+x^2}=x-5$$

I got $x=5$, but apparently it is wrong.

Please provide an explanation if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: try factorising the expression under the square root

Comment: I got x=5 but thats it

Comment: Im doing an online thing and when i type it it says its wrong

Comment: I did I got x=5

Comment: Maybe the reason you're stuck is because you've already solved the problem and that you're already finished, there's nothing else left to do. 

Is it asking for a single value of $x$ or multiple values?

Comment: **Quick everyone!!** Let's rush to close the question and downvote!  It's not like the OP is showing that he's engaged in the problem through the comments or anything.

Comment: @user46944 what?

Comment: @Dan I was being sarcastic.  Your question has been downvoted by 3 people and 1 person voted to close the question because the community prefers to see an individual's work or attempts at the problem.  However, you have shown through the comments that you are engaged in the problem, so I am annoyed that users in the community have rushed to downvote and try to close your question so quickly.  I think your engagement in the question is great, and I hope you continue to use this site when you need help.  :)

Comment: @user46944  Thank you, I will use this site again and I will try to be more engaged in the problem :)

Comment: @user46944 The thing which Dan will hopefully learn from this is that if that he has some information relevant to the question, he should add it to the post rather than in the comments. (So that they are better visible.) I agree with you, but I also understand that it easy to overlook something which is only mentioned in the comments. I voted to [leave open](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/505511). I guess that to access review you need 10k+ but maybe I am wrong - in which case you could vote to leave open too.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you for the heads up.  I am able to access the review page, and I just voted to leave this question open.

Answer (score 10):

HINT: $\sqrt{25-10x+x^2}=\sqrt{(5-x)^2}=|5-x|=|x-5|$. Thus, your equation can be rewritten as

$$|x-5|=x-5\;.$$

For what values of $x$ is that true? (Think about the definition of the absolute value.)

Comment: x is greater or equal to 5?

Comment: @Dan: That’s right.

Comment: Thank you so much Brian , I will be coming here next time if I need any help

Comment: @Dan: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The left hand side can be rewritten as:
$$
\sqrt{(x - 5)^2} = |x - 5|
$$
Do you know how to rewrite absolute values as piecewise functions? Try that. Note that there are two cases to consider: when $x < 5$ and when $x \geq 5$. Note that there are solutions other than $5$; for example, $x = 7$ is a solution (plugging it in to both sides yields $2 = 2$).

Answer (score -1):

This is an identity... or kinda. You see $\sqrt{x^2-10x+25}=\sqrt{(x-5)^2}=|x-5|$. So, if you are thinking that $x\geq 5$, then, you'll have $\sqrt{x^2-10x+25}=x-5$. So, this is not an equation.

Comment: so whats the answer?

Comment: It *is* an equation; it just has a lot of solutions.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott if you say so...

Comment: @Dan... I think I just said it

Comment: Downvoted for incorrect response: it is an equation and it's not an identity.

Comment: So.. you have to tell me that you "downvoted"... ok, let me put that in a place where  I can GAF. ;)